# Site gone from Google due to dmca complain

Tags: google, google-search-console

My sites traffic gone null but after Google receive one DMCA complain for my site. My site is a MP3 search engine so I can index copyright MP3 out of my knowledge. I received a message in webmasters tools in and I have removed the copyright content from my site but traffic from Google is not increasing.

Questions

- What is the problem?
- Do I need to tell Google that I have removed the copyright content from my site?
- If yes then why I have lost my site traffic from Google forever?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Google considered your sites out of guidelines.

If you corrected your sites, you can ask to Google to reconsider them [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=fr&answer=35843).

Now, just Google can decide the future of your sites (back to index or not).